# Using beforeShow in primefaces context menu is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to execute a metod before a `<p:contextMenu>` is displayed I was looking in the properties of the component and found `beforeShow` I'm not sure if I don't understand pretty well how this attribute works, but I tried to call the method with this

```
beforeShow="#{repositController.validate(item)}
```

and nothing happens when I do right click in the area, but the method is called once in the loading of the page.

The variable item come from the tree selection element. (I´dont know if that matters)

My java method is

```
public void validate(String cat) {
    this.name = cat;    
}
```

PD the the context menu is working right I just have that problem to run a method after display it.

thanks in advance for your time and answers.

Comment: beforeShow is client side, so you can only have script there. EL is not script

Comment: hi @JaqenH'ghar that is the answer please post it like an answer